# C++ Template method unknown return type

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++14, auto

I ran into a piece of code I do not follow. Consider the following 2 methods.

```
template <typename T>
auto FindElementV1(std::vector<T> elementList, const T& element) {
 return std::find(elementList.begin(), elementList.end(), element);     
}

template <typename T>
auto FindElementV2(std::vector<T> elementList, const T& element) -> typename decltype(elementList)::iterator {
 return std::find(elementList.begin(), elementList.end(), element);     
}
```

I can understand `FindElementV2` working as the return type for that method is specified using a `decltype`. But Why does `FindElementV1` work with no return type specified? Is `V1` a standard compliant piece of code?

Below is the full working example. Complied with gcc 6.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
auto FindElementV1(std::vector<T> elementList, const T& element) {
 return std::find(elementList.begin(), elementList.end(), element);     
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,4,2,4,3,5,3,5,3,6};
    auto it = FindElementV1(vec, 5); //< Why does this work without a return type in the method?
    cout<<*it<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[dcl.spec.auto]**
>
> If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is **deduced from non-discarded return statements, if any, in the body of the function**

and also

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has multiple non-discarded return statements, the return type is deduced for each such return statement. If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed.

A discarded statement is one that appears in a non-taken branch of a *constexpr if* statement **[stmt.if]**.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of non-discarded return statements? In other words, under what conditions would I have to specify the return type using decltype. Could I not always get away with using auto?

Comment: @cplusplusrat You do need to specify the return type if you have multiple return statements with different types being returned. I imagine that a discarded return statement refers to `if constexpr` branches that evaluated to false, but I don't know if there are other examples.

Comment: @cplusplusrat  See edits. You really should get yourself a copy of the draft standard. There's a helpful search function in most PDF readers.

Comment: @n.m. You got me, I was being lazy. Got the standard PDF draft.

Answer (score 1):

C++14 gave us the ability to write functions with deduced return type:

```
auto foo() { return 5; }
```

In C++11, this is ill-formed - you need to specify the return type somehow. In C++14, we can conservatively deduce the return type from the `return` statements. By conservatively, I mean that if there is more than one - they all need to be the same type, and if you recurse, you need to recurse 2nd and not 1st.

The deduction follows the normal template deduction rules. So this:

```
auto foo(int& i) { return i; }
```

returns an `int`, not `int&`.

All of which is to say, yes, `FindElementV1` is a perfectly valid function template... as of C++14.